# can read system call experience short count after it is interrupted by a signal?

Tags: linux-kernel, signals, system-calls

Let's say I call `read` to read 1000 bytes, and when `read` is reading the 501th bytes then a signal interrupts it, so does `read` return 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may do any of at least three things, depending on the type of file (disk, socket, pipe, terminal), and the timing of the signal.

(a) The signal may arrive before any data is transferred, in which case read() returns -1, and sets the errno to EINTR. The caller is expected to repeat the read() explicitly.

(b) The signal may be held off until the transfer completes, and return as normal, probably after the signal handler has been called.

(c) The read may return with a short count, which is not an error. This can also happen at the end of file, or when no further is currently available (e.g. on a pipe or socket), as well as when a signal has interrupted the transfer. The caller is expected to deal with short inputs, either by processing the data in variable-length sections, or by extra read() calls to complete the intent of the original transfer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the save -- my bad. I delved into fread() recently, which does return zero for EOF or error, and expects the caller to ask feof() and ferror().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. still a question, my understanding is,  a system call is consist of single machine instruction, how it can be interrupted by a signal, as the kernel will only check if a signal arrive after one instruction is finished, so a system call is atomic, it has to finish first before the kernel can detect the arrival of a signal?

Comment: The actual *call* is a very short sequence (in assembler, it also contains the args you pass, and sets up a stack frame for when the kernel resumes your program). But the Kernel runs the code for the action you called until it completes. If you do a read on a slow device (say a pipe or socket) your process might be held in the call for a week, until something sends a packet to you. For a disk, it might be a millisecond. Either way, several signals can arrive while your code is after your system call and before the return happens.

Comment: System calls are absolutely not atomic. By making a system call, your process usually forfeits its scheduled timeslice, and the scheduler will start another ready process in its place. The kernel services your syscall concurrently with every other process that has issued one, using its own queueing mechanisms, and some kernel-owned user-space threads. It also services other things like cache and timers. Signals do not all 'arrive' at the kernel: many are made because another process used the kill(2) system call to request them.